# Give simple HTTP 401 when trying to access some part of the web instead of redirect to login page

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I've made a spring page using Spring Security. When I try to access any url inside this page, if the session is not set, it will redirect you to the login page: /login. This is fine, but now I've made a simple http rest api inside this web. What I want if I try to access any url inside /api/** just drop the 401, instead of sending a HTTP redirect to login.

I have made a Filter with preHandle:

public class BusinessKeyInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

```
@Override
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {

    Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    if (auth != null && auth.isAuthenticated()
            &&
            // when Anonymous Authentication is enabled
            !(auth instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken)) {
       // other stuf ....
        }
    } else {
        if (request.getRequestURI().startsWith("/api")) {
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN);
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
}
```

But in this case request URI is already **/login**

My configuration:

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().sessionManagement()
                .invalidSessionUrl("/login?invalid")
                .and().csrf().disable().formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .failureHandler(customAuthenticationFailureHandler)
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/loggedIn")
                .usernameParameter("email")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .successHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler)
                .and().logout()
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/").and().exceptionHandling()
                .accessDeniedPage("/access-denied")
        ;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend not mixing your previous security configuration with your new REST api config. You could do the following:

```
@EnableWebSecurity 
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Configuration
    @Order(1)
    public static class WebConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.antMatchers("/web")
            ...
           /* Your previous config would go here */
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(2)
    public static class ApiConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.antMatchers("/web")

            ... /* Your /api configuration goes here */

                .exceptionHandling()
                  .authenticationEntryPoint(customAuthenticationEntryPoint)

        }

        @Bean
        AuthenticationEntryPoint customAuthenticationEntryPoint() {
            return new HttpStatusEntryPoint(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
        }
    }
}
```

This way, you could configure your rest api separately. Now you can have different a authentication entry point for your rest api. The fact is that you're most likely going to want to also provide a custom failure handler and success handler, which you can now do easily, and which will remain separate from the rest of your web application.